# why should I care about EXTENSION comments in boost documentation

Tags: c++, boost

By looking at boost documentation some of the classes and functions are commented as "EXTENSION"

for example like [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.threadgroup) one, what does this "EXTENSION" mean and why should I care about it?

the comment is supposed to give some notice, but what does it mean for casual learners such as myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at what is marked as `EXTENSION`, I can say that they are entities in `boost` which are not in the corresponding part of `std`. `boost::thread` and related can basically be used as a drop-in replacement for `std::thread`; the `EXTENSION` comments seem to mark additionaly bits which don't have the `std` equivalent.

Comment: Oh, thanks, this is probably yet another reason to prefer boost over std equivalent.